# Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression saving to database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to save the date from a date/time picker into my table where the DTPJobID = 1.

I'm using VB2010 and Microsoft Access 2003.  My table contains the following

```
Table Name: DTP
Fields
ID: Auto number
DTPJobID: Number
DTPDate: Date/Time with format of dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn
```

I use the following coding:-

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DB1.mdb")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [DTP] SET DTPDate = @p1 WHERE DTPJobID = @p2"
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.dtp.Value)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 1)
        End With
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

However, I get the following error:-

```
Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression
```

Any ideas where i might have gone wrong?

Comment: one of those 2 columns in the db does not match the data type being passed.  Maybe DTPDate is not a date type?

Comment: Thats strange, I changed the format in the database of DTPDate from Date/Time to Text and it worked? when I open up access the format it has saved it as is 2014-12-16 15:12:09 so it has saved it as American and included the seconds at the end.

Comment: if that is your actual SQL and actual Param code, it should treat DTP.Value as a date.  You might want to change the DB back to Date and examine Parameters just before the Execute to see what it is interpreting it as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date is in the wrong format so it is the wrong data type

Try

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.dtp.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"))
```