# Input the date of DateTimePicker in ms access using a query VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '7/27/2016 6:20:48 PM'.

I got this message every time I click the save button on my program.

here's the code:

```
Public Sub savetoDB()
    Dim mydate As DateTime
    mydate = Me.dtpDateDel.Value

    con.Open()
    Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Monitoring] ([Truck Plate No], [Driver], [Helper], [Date of Delivery], [Product], [Payment], [Customer]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, " & mydate & ", @p5, @p6, @p7)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cbxTruck.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cbxDriver.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cbxHelper.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", cbxProduct.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtPayment.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", txtCustomer.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Save Successfully!")
    End Using

End Sub
```

the error was thrown to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Don't pass the 'mydate' as plain text. Use a parameter like you've done with the other values.

Comment: I looked at your profile and it appears that you haven't marked any of the answers as correct in any of your questions posted. This should be done so that they are removed from the "unanswered questions" list and saves everyone some time :)

Comment: I'm so  sorry sir I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what happens when you do this?

```
Public Sub savetoDB()
Dim mydate As DateTime
    mydate = Me.dtpDateDel.Value

    con.Open()
    Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Monitoring] ([Truck Plate No], [Driver], [Helper], [Date of Delivery], [Product], [Payment], [Customer]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cbxTruck.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cbxDriver.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cbxHelper.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", mydate)
        // Alternatively you need to use something like this to format it correctly.
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", mydate.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", cbxProduct.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtPayment.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", txtCustomer.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Save Successfully!")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: It says  Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. and the error still thrown to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @Kenzakie20 Then check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091765/additional-information-data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-saving-to-data

Comment: @Kenzakie20 I've also edited the answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
Public Sub savetoDB()
Dim mydate As DateTime
mydate = Me.dtpDateDel.Value

con.Open()
Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Monitoring] ([Truck Plate No], [Driver], [Helper], [Date of Delivery], [Product], [Payment], [Customer]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)"
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cbxTruck.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cbxDriver.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cbxHelper.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", SqlDbType.Date ,mydate) 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", cbxProduct.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtPayment.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", txtCustomer.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Save Successfully!")
End Using
End Sub
```