# Data type mismatch on ms access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a problem on my program. it says "Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression." and the error was throw to `rs.Fill(dt)` here's my code

```
con.Open()

        Dim dt As New DataTable("tbl_Stock")
        Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [tbl_Stocks] WHERE [Product] ='" & lbPro.Text & "' AND [Batch ID] = '" & txtID.Text & "'", con)
        Dim ve As String
        rs.Fill(dt)


        ve = CStr(dt.Rows.Count)
        rs.Dispose()
        con.Close()
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  It would solve your problem, too, since Batch ID probably isn't a string value in the database.

Comment: [You clearly know about Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38610476/1070452) why arent you using the here?

Comment: The error is pretty much a catchall - usually the problem is a syntax error.

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do it? i just want to check if the batch id and product exist on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, *Batch ID* is numeric, thus no quotes:

```
Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [tbl_Stocks] WHERE [Product] ='" & lbPro.Text & "' AND [Batch ID] = " & txtID.Text & "", con)
```